# Dart & Flutter - Passing data across screens. NoSuchMethodError being caused by widget within MaterialPageRoute()

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, nosuchmethoderror

I tried passing data from a filter page to the home page, but keep getting the following error.
Error message on console - NoSuchMethodError being caused by widget within MaterialPageRoute()

```
//Radio button values to select user's gender on Filter Page
enum PrayditatorGender { Female, Male }
PrayditatorGender pGender;

//Radio button values to select Prayditation category on Filter Page
enum PrayditationFilter {
  All,
  Family,
  Fellowship,
  GodlyWisdom,
  GoodSuccess,
  HealthAndSafety,
}
PrayditationFilter pFilter = PrayditationFilter.All;


    //Code to push the data from Filter Page to Home Page
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) {
             PrayditatorHomePage(
              pGender: pGender,
              pFilter: pFilter
              )
    ));




    //Code to handle the data on Home Page
    class PrayditatorHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      final PrayditatorGender pGender;
      final PrayditationFilter pFilter;
      PrayditatorHomePage({this.pGender, this.pFilter});

      @override
      _PrayditatorHomePageState createState() => _PrayditatorHomePageState();
    }

    class _PrayditatorHomePageState extends State<PrayditatorHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots,  it is best if you paste your actual code. Anyway, since you are using a *StatefulWidget*, the way you access them in your state would be by using `widget.example`, to procure them from the widget. You don't need to create two separate constructors

Comment: Thanks... widget.variableName also runs well. However, the error message still persists when rendering.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help with that without seeing any code.

Comment: Code now posted...

Comment: It seems to be giving that error because `MaterialPageRoute` is expecting a return and you don't have one.  Try `return PrayditatorHomePage(
          pGender: pGender,
          pFilter: pFilter
          ) `

Comment: Thanks. So I changed the arrow function syntax to the code below, but same 'NoSuchMethodError' message why testing. Error still persists even with normal function syntax within MaterialPageRoute.

---
    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return PrayditatorHomePage(
                          pGender: pGender, pFilter: pFilter);
                    }));

Comment: Can you kindly show me what  `pGender: pGender,
          pFilter: pFilter` are, where are you declaring them?  Including `PrayditatorGender` and `PrayditationFilter ` what *type* are they?

Comment: @Unbreachable code now edited to show these. The variables (pGender and pFilter) are declared on the Filter Page as Enum types (PrayditatorGender and PrayditationFilter).

Answer (score 0):

**Your syntax is wrong, you're not supposed to be having this issue, this code worked with no issues:**

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PrayditatorHomePage(
          pGender: pGender,
          pFilter: pFilter,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, 'Dart Analysis' is all clear for all dart files. Please do you notice any syntax in the code pasted above?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for taking time to view/comment. Bug has been busted and code working effectively!

Syntax was all correct, however, a static parameter was inappropriately put in the place meant for a dynamic parameter. After all, lessons learned.